# Noise reduction showing no change at any zoom

Tags: noise-reduction, rawtherapee

I'm using RawTherapee and none of the noise reduction sliders make even the slightest difference, no matter how far I slide them. I've tried it at all different zoom levels, including 100% (the one I've read is necessary to actually see the change in the preview image). Not sure what to do. It's a very noisy image, so you'd think it would produce some change at least.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How long do you wait? I don't use RawTherapee, but many apps will take a while (anywhere from a few seconds to a couple of minutes depending on file sizes and the computer's specifications) to crunch the numbers for the entire image any time the NR settings is changed.

Comment: Oh I definitely wasn't waiting a whole minute. That sounds super tedious waiting to see if it did anything. I'd say I was giving it 15-30 second, staring at it to see if I saw any change haha

Comment: Depends on the kind of noise, can you post a relevant crop of the picture? Also the RT authors can be found [there](https://discuss.pixls.us/tags/c/processing/7/rawtherapee)

Comment: did you activate the noise reduction "master switch" on top of the noise reduction section? otherwise the sliders don't do anything.